# Sorted ouput, needs to have text inserted between string

Tags: bash, sorting

I trying to add text (predefined) between a sorted output and saved to a new file.

I'm using a curl command to gather my info.

```
$ curl --user XXX:1234!@# "http://......"
```

Then using grep to find IP addresses and sorting so they only appear once.

```
$ curl --user XXX:1234!@# "http://......" | grep -E -o -m1 '([0-9]{1,3}[\.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}' | sort -u
```

I need to add `<my_text_predefined> ([0-9]{1,3}[\.]){3}[0-9]{1,3} <my_text_predefined>` between the regex ip address and then saved to a new file.

The script below only get my the ip address

```
$ curl --user XXX:1234!@# "http://......" | grep -E -o -m1 '([0-9]{1,3}[\.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}' | sort -u
123.12.0.12
123.56.98.76
```

Comment: Please format your question so that it is easier to read.

Comment: @RClose I tried to edit your question, I have added code formatting to code snippets to your question, please edit your question further if I did something not ok. You said "I (am) trying to add text" - what do you mean by that? What do you want the output to be? Please post expected output that you want to get. You want to prefix each line with some predefined text? Suffix each line with some text? Or do you want to filter lines with some text?

Comment: I do want to add a prefix and suffix to each result. The prefix and suffix needs to be between the ip address.

Comment: please update your question with the desired output

Comment: Also, please clarify if the prefix and suffix are the same or different. Using `<my_text_predefined>` for both makes it look like they represent the same value.

Comment: You have to be careful processing `curl` output as it contains DOS `CRLF` line endings. I haven't tested with your case, but that itself can lead to processing problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if we need print some text for each IP ... try xargs

`for i in {1..100}; do echo $i; done | xargs -n1 echo "Values are:"`

if based on IP you would need to take decision put in a loop

`for file $(curl ...) do ...`
and check $file or do something with it ...

Comment: I think you meant `$(curl ...)` (change the left curly brace to a left parenthesis).

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! I was able to get what I was looking with: $ curl --user some_user:password "http://...." | grep -E -o -m1 '([0-9]{1,3}[\.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}' | sort -u | sed 's/.*/<prefix> -s & <suffix>/'

Answer (score 1):

`$ curl --user some_user:password "http://...." | grep -E -o -m1 '([0-9]{1,3}[\.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}' | sort -u | sed 's/.*/<prefix> -s & <suffix>/'`